# How do I securely use a REST API solely from within a web browser?

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, oauth, client-side

I'm trying to find a way to interact securely with an OAuth (draft v2-23) API completely in the browser. There are obvious security concerns with authenticating in the browser because the auth token and other keys are exposed somewhere in the browser.

Is there a secure way to hide those keys, or am I limited to creating a server side solution that keeps track of those keys?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this very concern when working with the mobile version of my application (since a normal login auth wouldn't work.)

The solution I came up with is to work with 2 keys. When the user logs in, they are initially given *their* token. The client already has the token saved as a variable in the app (you can make the token whatever string you want, I usually generate a base64 key of 32 length.)

So this is the basic play by play of what happens when they call the server from a GET/PUT/etc..

1. Send request with `USER TOKEN` and `SERVER TOKEN` as parameters.
2. `SERVER TOKEN` is checked against the server token (which is salted and hashed). (If `SERVER TOKEN` is good, proceed to step 3, else deny request here.
3. `USER TOKEN` is checked against the user token assigned to said user (which is salted and hashed) and makes sure it exists. If good, proceed to step 4, else deny request here.
4. Execute request (GET/PUT/DEL/POST etc.)

Long story short, i keep a salted and hashed version of the user tokens (which are unique to the user) and the server tokens (which is the same for every user) on the server and the de-salting and de-hashing is done on the back end.

I hope this *kinda* makes sense. It might not be the standard or completely right but it's what i understood token auth to be and this works for me.

If others see something wrong with my reasoning please chime in and tell me so.

Comment: My problem is that I don't have control over how the back-end works.

Comment: Well then... that is a problem. Let me think on this and get back to you.

Comment: At this point I've decided to use a server in the backend to interact with the REST api, so don't sweat it. If you find a solution, great, but don't spend too much effort on finding one.